# Kotlin で配列同士の引き算をするには

Tags: java, android, kotlin

以下のように、Floatの配列array1とarray2があった場合
そのまま引き算のように記述するとエラーになります。

```
var array1 = floatArrayOf(10.toFloat(), 8.toFloat(), 5.toFloat())
var array2 = floatArrayOf(4.toFloat(), 3.toFloat(), 2.toFloat())

var array3 = array1 - array2
```

得たい値(配列)は以下のようなものです。

```
[6.0,5.0,3.0]
```

Kotlinでは、配列同士の引き算をどのように記述するのが良いですか？

ちなみに私はKotlin初心者なので、`10.toFloat()`のような書き方があまりスマートではないと感じています。
Floatの配列を作成する時にもっと良い方法があったらそれも知りたいです。

Comment: `array1.zip(array2, Float::minus)` と書くことができますが、スマートではないですね。。。

Comment: 同じ趣旨の質問がありました。こちらも参考になると思います: [How do I get the sums for all elements of two lists in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48431672/4506703)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そのまま引き算のように記述すると

というのがどの言語を念頭に置いているのかわかりませんが、*配列同士の引き算*ということ自体が、例えば Java では元々やらない発想ですね。あと、`.toFloat()` については、値に `f` を付ければいいのは Java と同じかと。

```
var array1 = floatArrayOf(10f, 8f, 5f)
var array2 = floatArrayOf(4f, 3f, 2f)
var array3 = Array(3){array1[it] - array2[it]}

array3.forEach{f -> println(f)}
```

for ループ的にやってみましたが、想定されているもの（*配列同士の引き算*）とは違うかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

zipして、計算。

```
$ kotlinc
>>> val array1 = floatArrayOf(10.toFloat(), 8.toFloat(), 5.toFloat())
>>> val array2 = floatArrayOf(4.toFloat(), 3.toFloat(), 2.toFloat())

>>> array1.zip(array2).map{(a, b) -> a - b}
res12: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Float> = [6.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```